# Video streaming from mobile to desktop using node.js and websockets

Tags: node.js, websocket, opera

We are using the following sample to do a video streaming POC in one of our apps:
http://francisshanahan.com/index.php/2011/stream-a-webcam-using-javascript-nodejs-android-opera-mobile-web-sockets-and-html5/

The POC uses Node.js and websockets to do a real-time video streaming from Mobile (using Opera Mobile browser) to Opera browser in desktop.
The app was working well a couple of months back. Recently we had format the OS in mobile with Android 4.1 Jellybean and re-installed Opera Mobile.

With the same browser settings, the video streaming now doesn’t work from mobile. The streaming works from another Opera browser instance on the same PC though.

With the logs we could see that the messages are sent successfully from the server, but the onmessage event doesn’t get triggered at all at the receiving end on the client.

Currently we are using Opera 12, that has the support of both Websockets and getUserMedia for streaming native web camera.
We have tried other different Opera browsers available for both mobile and desktop, but with no luck.

Any suggestion on getting this woking?

Thanks